# Receiving pre-request instead of wanted request

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, python-requests

The function below executes a simple request to the following link:
http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=test

All I want is to get the test-message "test" in those big ACSII letters.

However, for some reason the *output text* I'm looking for is not in the HTML code saved in the protocol. If I copy and paste the link and inspect the HTML code instead using Google Chrome, the *output text* is visible.

It seems like I'm only receiving the *pre-request* where the body part hasn't been generated yet. How do I get the "right" HTML source code where the *output_text* has been generated?

Below is:

1. The Python code
2. The HTML code received via requests
3. The HTML code when inspecting the page manually via chrome

### 1. Python Code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def scrape():
    """Scrape from http://patorjk.com

    Crucial section looks like:

        <pre id="taag_output_text" style="float:left;" class="fig" contenteditable="true">
        STRING STRING STRING STRING
        STRING STRING STRING STRING
        </pre>
    """

    URL = "http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=TEST"

    with requests.Session() as c:
        source = c.get(URL)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "lxml")

    with open("protocol.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(soup.prettify())

    text = soup.find("pre", id_="taag_output_text")

    if not(text):
        print("Error: output text not found.")

    return text
```

### 2. HTML Code via requests

```
  <div id="maincontent">
   <div id="outputFigDisplay">
   </div>
```

### 3. HTML Code via manual inspection

```
<div id="maincontent">
    <div id="outputFigDisplay" class="fig">
        <pre id="taag_output_text" style="float:left;" class="fig" contenteditable="true">  __                   __   
        _/  |_  ____   _______/  |_ 
        \   __\/ __ \ /  ___/\   __\
         |  | \  ___/ \___ \  |  |  
         |__|  \___  >____  > |__|  
                   \/     \/        
        </pre>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's generated client-side in the JS - it won't be visible anywhere on the server.

Comment: so there is no way of accessing it? Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the text is generated by js on client-side so it won't be possible to scrape it with `requests` and `bs4`, but you could use a client that runs js, like [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/):

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=TEST"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("taag_output_text")
text = element.text
driver.close()

print(text)
```

Alternatively, you can get the same ASCII art from http://www.network-science.de/ascii/ , without having to use `selenium`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.network-science.de/ascii/ascii.php?TEXT=TEST&FONT=graffiti&RICH=no&FORM=left&STRE=no&WIDT=80"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find_all('pre')[1].text

print(text)
```

Both methods produce the same results:

```
______________________ ____________________
\__    ___/\_   _____//   _____/\__    ___/
  |    |    |    __)_ \_____  \   |    |
  |    |    |        \/        \  |    |
  |____|   /_______  /_______  /  |____|
                   \/        \/
```